# Plone 4.0.4 and WebDAV

Tags: webdav, plone

Ive been looking at

http://plone.org/documentation/kb/webdav
  http://plone.org/documentation/kb/more-webdav

and Im able to connect to port 1980 with cadaver (on FreeBSD).

I have a simple setup of Plone behind Apache using (ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse).

So far so good. Now I would like Apache to proxy (or rewrite) WebDAV requests to the
WebDAV server. Users must only see their personal "member folder" with WebDAV - not root or other member folders, when using Netdrive (or other util to map a drive in the file explorer).

I would be happy if someone could direct me to a simple tutorial showing the rewrite rules (not ProxyPass as I understand) in Apache VirtualHost.

Thanks.
Nikolaj G.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ProxyPass can work.  I have some sites using ProxyPass, others using RewriteRule. The documentation under your Zope VirtualHostMonster is another good place.

The rewriting is as simple as this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  webdav.example.ca
    ServerAlias somethingelse
    ServerAdmin email@example.ca
```

So, I'm assuming you are going to have a specific hostname for the DAV server - in this case webdav.example.ca.

```
    RewriteLogLevel 0
    RewriteEngine On
```

You can't use Rewrite until you turn it on :-)

```
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost:1980/VirtualHostBase/http/webdav.example.ca:80/Plone/Members/VirtualHostRoot$1 [L,P]
```

The part before **VirtuaLHostBase** is the actual host/port your DAV server is on.  The next part **http/webdav.example.ca:80** describes the **protocol//:server:port** you want the users to use.  **Plone** would be your Plone Site name.  **$1** matches the regular expression **(.*)**.

```
</VirtualHost>
```

Testing it is as easy as using cadaver from your DAV server.  First make sure that you can access:

```
http://localhost:1980/Plone/Members/username
```

Then:

```
http://localhost:1980/VirtualHostBase/http/webdav.example.ca:80/Plone/Members/VirtualHostRoot/username
```

Finally:

```
http://webdav.example.ca:80/username
```

Now, this doesn't prevent a user from trying to attach to somebody else's folder, but Zope security does.  There's a bit of a chicken and egg situation in that the server doesn't know the username until after you have already used this.

Comment: Hi Auspex, I did not know about the point system - just gave you credit for your help. Thanks again. Nikolaj